# Customer management

Tags: crm, saas

I'm looking for a software/website to see my clients' maintenance contracts.

For example, the customer X has a contract for 12 repairs, he makes one, I would like that on my software/website I can see that it remains 11

I searched a lot on google but I didn't find anything (probably due to a bad search)

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you should search for things like:

- vehicle maintenance software
- fleet maintenance software

The other alternative is to use one of the open source CRM systems like [SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) for this:

- You can set up a Customer as an "Account".
- You can use tasks for each repair, or setup a "Repair". Once reapired, the task can be closed.
- It has Notes so can be assigned to each account.
- It is PHP/MySql, Open source, so can be self-hosted.
- It probably has much more than you need (Calls, Meetings, etc). So you may have to hide or disable some of the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain we could set something like that up in either dynamics 365 and possibly through Micorsoft's PowerApps instead as a cheaper alternative.

You would enter contracts you've signed into the system and within the contract form input how many fixes are allotted for each individual contract. You would then use microsoft flow to subtract this value from how many repairs you've done. Which means you would need a second form for repairs done.
Not sure if your a DIY person to where any of that made sense to you.